# Google sceneform 3D import

Tags: android, 3d, assets, sceneform

Hi I am trying to import a 3D object in Android Studio.

What I have done so far:

- Installed the Google Sceneform tools(beta) Plugin (1.15.0 version) (and restart Android Studio)
- Create a sampledata Directory in my app Directory
- Put in my obj and mtl file(andy.obj and andy.mtl)
- Add in the build.gradle file (in the app directory)
  the following things:

  1. apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

  2.sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/andy.obj',
      'default',
      'sampledata/models/andy.sfa',
      'src/main/res/raw/andy')

  3.(in dependencies) classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'

When I try to then right click on andy.obj and select import Sceneform Asset then click finish, I  get this:
import failed
Gradle build failed with new import rules. Would you like to revert the changes.

How do I resolve this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me clear one thing.
If you have wrote this code into your build.gradle file

"sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/andy.obj', 'default', 'sampledata/models/andy.sfa', 'src/main/res/raw/andy')"

Then there is no need to do this step 
"right click on andy.obj and select import Sceneform Asset then click finish".

When you put above code into your build.gradle file and after click "Sync Now", **you just need to Rebuild your project and you will find your andy.sfb file at this path "src/main/res/raw/"**

Also I want to tell you one more thing that If you are using Android Studio 3.6 then the  Sceneform Plugin Version 1.15.0 will not work as expected as it is not compatible with Studio 3.6. Please check the reported issue here[https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/1078]